# How to open a specific csv file from server on load in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, csv

I'm a total noob regarding any kind of development, and after a lot of search online I realized that even if I find the answer to my problem I may not recognize it. So I have 0 coding skills, and at work I have to do a demo of a Digital Signage solution from Samsung, those are basically some displays that can output information from lan, and it also has a build in webbrowser that is HTML5 compliant.

For this demo I have to show how a display like that might be used in a production environment and receive information for display from a server. I've managed to install apache and I can make the display access my webpage but because this is just a display I don't have any input options.

Considering it's only a demo it isn't justified to contract development of an HTML5 app so I was thinking to just show a CSV file, preferably one that it's displayed line by line like that info was sent by a machine.

I've found source code to make my page open an CSV file, but it's not good for me considering I have no input method. Also, I understand that I can't automatically open a CSV file on the client side, and it's ok, my CSV will be stored in the same folder as my index.html.

So here is the code I've found, how can it be made to open data.csv automatically when the page is accessed and preferably display the information one line at time with a couple of seconds delay? Thanks

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head>
     <title></title>
     <style type="text/css">
         body
         {
             font-family: Arial;
             font-size: 10pt;
             background-color: #F7F7F7;
         }
         table
         {
             border: 1px solid #ccc;
         }
         table th
         {
             background-color: #F7F7F7;
             color: #333;
             font-weight: bold;
         }
         table th, table td
         {
             padding: 5px;
             border-color: #ccc;
         }
     </style>
</head>
<body> 
<script type="text/javascript">
function Upload() {
     var fileUpload = document.getElementById("fileUpload");
     var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.csv|.txt)$/;
     if (regex.test(fileUpload.value.toLowerCase())) {
         if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
             var reader = new FileReader();
             reader.onload = function (e) {
                 var table = document.createElement("table");
                 var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");
                 for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                     var row = table.insertRow(-1);
                     var cells = rows[i].split(",");
                     for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
                         var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                         cell.innerHTML = cells[j];
                     }
                 }
                 var dvCSV = document.getElementById("dvCSV");
                 dvCSV.innerHTML = "";
                 dvCSV.appendChild(table);
             }
             reader.readAsText(fileUpload.files[0]);
         } else {
             alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
         }
     } else {
         alert("Please upload a valid CSV file.");
     } 
}
window.onload = Upload('contacts.csv');
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="fileUpload" />
    <input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload" onclick = "Upload('contacts.csv')" /> 
    <hr />
    <div id="dvCSV"> </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you cannot do that for user security reasons, javascript cannot trigger or simulate a file open, user needs to click on the element to trigger file open. Try reading the csv file using [XmlHttpRequest (ajax)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Answer (score 0):

Thank's for your prompt response, you sent me in the right direction and from there I was able to find a script that solves my problem. So if my question comes up in future search the code that solved the problem for me below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
#container { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 1020px;}
</style>
<title>Informatii linie productie 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align="center" style="margin-top:150px; margin-bottom:30px;">Informatii linie productie 1</h1>
<div id="container">
<script>
 function autoRefresh()
{
    window.location = window.location.href;
}
 setInterval('autoRefresh()', 5000);
</script>
</div>
</body>
<script>
$.get('data.csv', function(data) {
    var html = '<table class="table table-bordered">';
    var rows = data.split("\n");
    rows.forEach( function getvalues(ourrow) {
        html += "<tr>";
        var columns = ourrow.split(",");
        html += "<td>" + columns[0] + "</td>";
        html += "<td>" + columns[1] + "</td>";
        html += "<td>" + columns[2] + "</td>";
        html += "<td>" + columns[3] + "</td>";
        html += "<td>" + columns[4] + "</td>";
        html += "<td>" + columns[5] + "</td>";
        html += "<td>" + columns[6] + "</td>";
        html += "</tr>";
    })
    html += "</table>";
    $('#container').append(html);
});
</script>
</html>
```